# PDFsharp watermark text starts in center on document

Tags: pdfsharp

I'm trying to use the watermark in PDFsharp. I'm following the sample that is on their website, but when I try and draw the watermark the text starts in the center of the screen and not the bottom left hand corner.

```
 XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);
 var font = new XFont("Helvetica", 30, XFontStyle.Regular);
 var watermark = "DRAFT";
 XSize size = gfx.MeasureString(watermark, font);

 // Define a rotation transformation at the center of the page

 gfx.TranslateTransform(page.Width / 2, page.Height / 2);

 gfx.RotateTransform(-Math.Atan(page.Height / page.Width) * 180 / Math.PI);

 gfx.TranslateTransform(-page.Width / 2, -page.Height / 2);

 // Create a graphical path

 XGraphicsPath path = new XGraphicsPath();

 // Add the text to the path

 path.AddString(watermark, font.FontFamily, XFontStyle.BoldItalic, 150,
                new XPoint((page.Width - (size.Width * 2)) / 2, (page.Height - size.Height) / 2), 
                XStringFormats.Default);


 // Create a dimmed red pen and brush
 XPen pen = new XPen(XColor.FromArgb(50, 75, 0, 130), 3);

 XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(50, 106, 90, 205));

 // Stroke the outline of the path
 gfx.DrawPath(pen, brush, path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PDFsharp 1.50 beta, then replace `XStringFormats.Default` with `XStringFormats.TopLeft` when calling `path.AddString`.

**Update:** You are calling `MeasureString` with a font size of 30, but draw the text with a font size of 150. The position of the text is therefore calculated based on incorrect values for text width and height and the watermark is drawn at the wrong place.

`XStringFormats.TopLeft` is correct (PDFsharp 1.50 needs it, PDFsharp 1.32 ignores it), but does not fix the problem caused by using different font sizes for calculation and for drawing.

Comment: No, using version 1.32.3057.0 changing to TopLeft didn't affect anything. Changing it to .Center kinda works. Still looks slightly off but much better. thanks